# Disjunction distribution property in lisp

Tags: functional-programming, lisp

Basically I need to represent this property down below as a function in lisp

(p and q) or (r and t) = (p or r) and (p or t) and (q or r) and (q or t)

The function distribute-or (fbf)  takes as an argument a formula of the type

`(or (and a b) c )`  and transforms it in `(and (or a c) (or b c))`

But, the problem is you don't know how many arguments the or-formula can have and which are leterals and which are conjunctions of leterals.
It can be any of the following examples

`(or a b)` leaves it as it is

`(or a b c (and d e f)` should become `(and (or a b c d) (or a b c e) (or a b c f)`
`(or (and a b) (and d e))` which turn it in `(and (or a d) (or a e) (or b d) (or b e))`

I can design a function only if "or" has 2 arguments but I dont know how to do it if it has more.

Comment: It's part of some project Im doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't wrote your version of `distribute-or`, I suggest this variant, which takes fbf of any length, but doesn't work in depth.

```
(defun dekart-product (sets)
  (if (null sets)
      (list '())
      (let ((prod (dekart-product (cdr sets))))
        (mapcan #'(lambda (lst) 
                    (mapcar #'(lambda (el) (cons el lst))
                            (car sets)))
                prod))))

(defun collect-ands (l)
  (mapcar #'(lambda (el)
              (if (and (consp el)
                       (eq 'and (car el)))
                  (cdr el)
                  (list el)))
          l))

(defun distribute-or (fbf)
  (if (and (consp fbf)
           (eq 'or (car fbf)))
      (cons 'and (mapcar #'(lambda (lst) (cons 'or lst))
                         (dekart-product
                                (collect-ands (cdr fbf)))))
      fbf))
```

And it's result:

```
(distribute-or '(or a b c (and d e f)))
;=> (AND (OR A B C D) (OR A B C E) (OR A B C F))
```

It works by a simple manner:

- Collect all arguments of and expressions into sets:
  `(or (and a b c) (and e f) g)` --> `((a b c) (e f) (g))`
- Then make a dekart-product ([Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) in other words) of all collected sets
- And form the output expression, just by adding `'or` and `'and`, where neccesary

Answer (score 0):

So, you already have a function `f` which can transform `((a b) (c d))` into `((a c) (a d) (b c) (b d))` (I am omitting `and`s and `or`s).

You need a function which would transform `((a b) (c d) (e f))` into `((a c e) (a c f) (a d e) (a d f) (b c e) (b c f) (b d e) (b d f))`.

This seems to be a clear case for [`reduce`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_reduce.htm): `(reduce #'f mylist)`.